# Python - NameError: name itemgetter not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I just started learning Python came across this very simple code could not get it right:

```
import operator;

b=[(5,3),(1,3),(1,2),(2,-1),(4,9)]
sorted(b,key=itemgetter(1))
```

I got the error:

> NameError: name 'itemgetter' is not defined.

Any idea?

Comment: Try `from operator import itemgetter` or `sorted(b,key=operator.itemgetter(1))`.

Comment: Either you do `operator.itemgetter` or `from operator import itemgetter`.

Comment: The semicolon is burning my eyes!

Comment: Thanks. it fixed by using from operator import itemgetter;

Answer (score 23):

you must import the module like,

```
import operator

b=[(5,3),(1,3),(1,2),(2,-1),(4,9)]
sorted(b,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 5):

to write `itemgetter` instead of `operator.itemgetter` can do

```
from operator import itemgetter
```